# Is $2^{1093}-2 $ divisible by $1093^2$?

Tags: elementary-number-theory, divisibility

Is $2^{1093}-2 $ divisible by $1093^2$?

I tried to use Euler' theorem with this theorem

$(a,m)=1, a \equiv \alpha \pmod{m}, b \equiv \beta \pmod{\varphi(m)}$ then $a^b \equiv \alpha^\beta $
but not to find solution.

Comment: idunno my first guess would be binary exponentiation $\mod 1093^2$ and see what we get but there might be a less generative approach that looks neater

Comment: Yes, $2^{1093}-2$ is divisible by $1093^2$.

Comment: $1093$ is a [Wieferich prime](https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Wieferich_prime)

Comment: I would just feed it to [Alpha](https://www.wolframalpha.com/input/?i=2%5E1093-2+mod+1093%5E2) and see that it is.

Comment: Euler's theorem tells you $1093\mid2^{1092}-1$, which divides $2^{1093}-2 $, since $1093$ is prime; that holds for all primes, but $1093$ is unusual in that it's also true for $ 1093^2$

Answer (score 3):

Yes.  I did these calculations on my phone:

$1093^2= 1194649.$

$2^4=16$;
$2^8=256$;
$2^{16}=65536$;
$2^{32}=65536^2=4294967296\equiv204141\bmod 1194649$;
$2^{64}\equiv204141^2=41673547881\equiv606814\bmod1194649$;
$2^{128}\equiv606814^2=368223230596\equiv153273\bmod1194649$; and
$2^{256}\equiv153273^2=23492612529\equiv1034593\bmod1194649$.

Therefore $2^{364}\equiv2^42^82^{32}2^{64}2^{256}\equiv16\times256\times204141\times606814\times1034593\equiv 1\bmod1194649$.

Therefore $2^{1093}=(2^{364})^32\equiv2\bmod 1093^2.$

So $1093$ is a Wieferich prime.  According to [Wikipedia](https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Wieferich_prime), the only other known Wieferich prime is $3511$.

Comment: In retrospect, it might have been a bit easier to show that $2^{91}-2^{46}\equiv-1\bmod 1093^2$ and $2^{1092}-1=(2^{91}-2^{46}+1)(2^{91}+2^{46}+1)(2^{182}-1)(2^{728}+2^{364}+1)$

Answer (score 0):

Alternatively, using MS Excel spreadsheet:
$$2^{1093}-2= 2(2^{1092}-1)=2(2^{546}-1)(2^{546}+1)=2(2^{546}-1)(\color{red}{2^{182}+1})(2^{364}-2^{182}+1)\\
===================================\\
2^{26}=67,108,864\equiv 75\cdot 1093^2+208,520\equiv 208,520 \pmod{1093^2}\\
2^{182}\equiv (2^{26})^7\equiv 208,520^7\equiv (208,520^2)^3\cdot 208,520\equiv 145,396^3\cdot 208,520\equiv \\
145,396^2\cdot 145,396\cdot 208,520\equiv 682,761\cdot 145,396\cdot 208,520\equiv \\
165,052\cdot 208,520 \equiv -1 \pmod{1093^2=1,194,649}$$